# Kinect Face Recognition sdk 1.5 to sdk 1.8

Tags: sdk, kinect, face-recognition

I try to run facial recognition kinect. 
I want to convert the code sdk sdk 1.5 to 1.8. How do I replace this:

```
if (kinect != null)
        {
            //Initialize to return Color images
            kinect.Initialize(RuntimeOptions.UseColor);//<---this

            //Initialize Image Flux
            kinect.VideoFrameReady += new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(nui_VideoFrameReady);//<---this
            kinect.VideoStream.Open(ImageStreamType.Video, 2, ImageResolution.Resolution640x480, ImageType.Color);//<---this
        }
    }

    void nui_VideoFrameReady(object sender, ImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)//<---this
    {
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What language are you using? I am assuming C# but you say v1.5 which would make me think C++ with these naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Start()
{
    KinectSensor kinect = KinectSensor.KinectSensors.FirstOrDefault();
    if (kinect != null)
    {
        kinect.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
        kinect.ColorFrameReady += OnColorFrameReady;
        kinect.Start();
    }
}

void OnColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs args)
{
}
```